# How to set onClickListener for items in a ListView (items of listview are generated dynamically by retreiving data from firebase)

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

Hi Iam trying to make a chatApp.Iam successful with initial steps like user authentication,registration.After a successfull login user gets a screen as shown in this image:

[image: User Interface for a user]
Now the list of users here are generated by following code:

```
ListView listView;
View view;
ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
String name;
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference root = db.getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = root.child("users");

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users,container,false);
   listView =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
   final ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
     (getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,usernames);
   listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

   userRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
       String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
       try
       {
         JSONObject object = new JSONObject(value);
         name = object.getString("username");
       }
       catch(JSONException e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

       usernames.add(name);
       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

     @Override
     public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

     @Override
     public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
  });

  return view;
}
```

Now whenever user clicks on particular name I've to take him to a messageActivity(more precisely another activity). Please tell me how I can add onClickListeners or any other possible method to do this?

Comment: you need own adapter instead `ArrayAdapter` and there you can set your `onClickListener`. Instead `ListView` you should better use `RecyclerView`

Comment: I initially tried with a recycler view but I was unable to do it so i shifted to ListView

Comment: [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java) you can find more about `RecyclerView`

Comment: `ListView` is deprecated. You should switch to `RecyclerView`

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Declare this in your fragment or activity

```
private OnItemClickListener listPairedClickItem = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        String personName = usernames.get(position);
        Toast.makeText( context, "listview clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(currenactivityname.this, activitytolaunchname.class);
        intent.putExtra("username",personName ); //get this name in next activity and show in title  bar
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( listPairedClickItem );
```

Comment: Thankyou very much It's working. But how should I redirect user to new Interface for a chat with that person. For example I clicked on name of karthik from list above the I should somehow redirect my user to chatActivity with title karthik. So how should I access that name karthik

Comment: okay , for that create an activity like ChatDetailActivity with the title bar of person's name , change the title accordingly and launch that activity on listview item click

Answer (score 1):

After

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

create your listener like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do what you want here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onItemClickListener :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
      String selectedName = usernames.get(position);
      // Do what you want with username here

   }
});
```